# how to add footer with dynamic jasper other than Autotext in PDF format?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

How i can add long text in footer of dynamic jasper report in pdf?

Actually i am developing one report with chinese characters and i need to add content in footer but when i add it using AutoText it just print empty space.
so looking for solution how i can add it

```
drb.addAutoText("<unicode of chinese chars>",
            AutoText.POSITION_FOOTER, AutoText.ALIGMENT_LEFT,800,atStyle);
```

If same code is used for Header it works and prints chinese chars by just replacing AutoText.POSITION_HEADER

I am using *DynamicJasper* because *JasperReports* is not able to print chinese chars.

Answer (score 0):

Jasper can print Chinese characters. Just choose *Simsun* or *Sans serif* fonts. You can put **footer** or **header** or even **last page footer**. Then place your **text field** on the footer band and there you go.[image: sample template with header, footer and displays Chinese characters.]

Comment: If you run this with pdf output it will print blank , if it open pdf with ireport inbuilt pdf viewer than it prints chinese also when you use this jrxml with some application and you pass chinese chars it will print blank.

Comment: im sorry just trying to help,have you tried using "identity-h"? in the property?  for reference..  [link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/539404/displaying-chinese-characters-pdf)

Comment: It's ok, if you check in ireport it shows it deprecated so still we add it than report does not print anything for Chinese chars.

Comment: the link you shared was for iReport 3.7.1 and i am working on ireport 5.5